# How to use downloaded JSON object stored in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, json

I am using SZJsonParser to download JSON object from a site.
Here's my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SZJsonParser.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        // insert code here...
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://mymovieapi.com/?title=Cars"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray *arr = [str jsonObject];
        for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i ++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the Terminal app, here's the output:

```
2013-09-19 15:54:49.957 SimpleJSONTerminal[24160:303] {
    actors =     (
        "Owen Wilson",
        "Paul Newman",
        "Bonnie Hunt",
        "Larry the Cable Guy",
        "Cheech Marin",
        "Tony Shalhoub",
        "Guido Quaroni",
        "Jenifer Lewis",
        "Paul Dooley",
        "Michael Wallis",
        "George Carlin",
        "Katherine Helmond",
        "John Ratzenberger",
        "Joe Ranft",
        "Michael Keaton"
    );
    "also_known_as" =     (
        "Cars - Quatre roues"
    );
    country =     (
        USA
    );
    directors =     (
        "John Lasseter",
        "Joe Ranft"
    );
    genres =     (
        Animation,
        Adventure,
        Comedy,
        Family,
        Sport
    );
    "imdb_id" = tt0317219;
    "imdb_url" = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/";
    language =     (
        English,
        Italian,
        Japanese,
        Yiddish
    );
    "plot_simple" = "A hot-shot race-car named Lightning McQueen gets waylaid in Radiator Springs, where he finds the true meaning of friendship and family.";
    poster =     {
        cover = "http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/317/219.jpg!cover?_upt=65f114a91379629498";
        imdb = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTE5Mzk5MTA2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTY3NTc2._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg";
    };
    rating = "7.3";
    "rating_count" = 150431;
    "release_date" = 20060822;
    runtime =     (
        "117 min"
    );
    title = "Cars - Quatre roues\n            \"Cars\"";
    type = VG;
    writers =     (
        "John Lasseter",
        "Joe Ranft"
    );
    year = 2006;
}
```

How do I store this in an NSDictionary so that I can use the "title" as a Key and then get the information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"]];

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *jsonData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *result = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&err] : nil;

if(err)
{

            NSLog(@"JSON Failed. Error - %@ %@",
                 [err localizedDescription],
                 [[err userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
else
{
    // Do what you have to do with your data
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Add breakpoints and tell me where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Usethis........ 


NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://mymovieapi.com/?title=Cars"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                          propertyListWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                          options:kNilOptions
                          format:NULL
                          error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"dict:%@",dict);
```

Comment: `2013-09-19 18:49:39.288 SimpleJSONTerminal[24198:303] dict:(null)`

That's the result.